# Touchpad and wlan not working in lenovoThinkbook 14-iil with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I try ubuntu 18.04/16.04 in lenovoThinkbook 14-iil. In both cases wifi and touchpad is not working. Please help me to resolve the issue Thanks in advance .
bellow are some logs:

```
Lenovo-ThinkBook-14-IIL:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:a9:fc:b7:b1:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:54:2f:7e:75:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.29.139/24 brd 192.168.29.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s20f3
       valid_lft 3407sec preferred_lft 3407sec
    inet6 2405:201:8803:bec9:34b9:332c:af58:260b/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 2232sec preferred_lft 2232sec
    inet6 2405:201:8803:bec9:baa3:f7a2:48c5:5f10/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 2232sec preferred_lft 2232sec
    inet6 fe80::c5b3:7e88:f132:61a/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


Lenovo-ThinkBook-14-IIL:~$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no


Lenovo-ThinkBook-14-IIL:~$ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8a02 (rev 03)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3852
Kernel driver in use: icl_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a56 (rev 07)
DeviceName: To Be Filled by O.E.M.
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3852
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a03 (rev 03)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3852
Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (rev 03)
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lenovo Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 34ef (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW) (rev 30)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW)
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lenovo Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Management Engine Interface (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lenovo Management Engine Interface
Kernel driver in use: mei_me
Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lenovo Ice Lake-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 30)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34b2 (rev 30)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lenovo Ice Lake-LP Serial IO UART Controller
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lenovo Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lenovo Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lenovo Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller
Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lenovo Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lenovo RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader
Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

Comment: Please add the output of `ip a`, `rfkill list` and `lspci -k`

Comment: Hello Sir, Please see the question again with log